# Angular 5 - The Design Container Not Showing In Full Page

Tags: angular, angular-material

i made my first angular 5 demo application but it not appears in full page
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcCKo.png)

here is the code

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>MyMaterial</span>

    <span class="example-spacer"></span>

    <button mat-button>About</button>
    <button mat-button>Services</button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>


  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name">
  </mat-form-field>
  </mat-selection-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check what is applying that padding/margin on your page. Downvoted as there is no way to reproduce your issue with the provided code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers are has default padding on html / body tag, to reset it put this into your css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can try it yourself with this snippet:

```css
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f0f;
}

html:hover, body:hover {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```